# In Samsung galaxy s9 while Accessibility "screen reader" is on and its not functioning properly?

Tags: android, accessibility, samsung-mobile, screen-readers, talkback

The accessibility Screen reader is not working properly in Samsung galaxy s9 in App. and while in other device have talkback is reading and functioning properly.
But why it's not functioning properly only in Samsung galaxy s9?
"For WCAG Standards it's not functioning properly and we need to fix the issue or we can exclude that specific device"

I tried one plus 6T with Accessibility Talkback feature its functioning properly for my App. but specifically only in Samsung Galaxy S9 is not working properly.

Why other android devices have talkback but only Samsung galaxy has screenreader anyone give example.

Comment: Hi there. Is this a programming question? Perhaps you should ask this on one of the Android forums. Regards.

Comment: _"Why other android devices have talkback but only Samsung galaxy has screenreader"_ Only Samsung knows, I suppose. There are ways to programmatically recognise the brand and model of a device, if you need to make some Samsung specific hacks.

Comment: It's programmatically, while other devices on talkback it's working properly but specifically, only Samsung device doesn't read the button label and not to go the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung devices have their own screen reader solution, called Voice Assistant (if I'm not mistaken). This is quite similar to TalkBack, but in some ways it behaves differently, indeed. As there are no specific clues in your question, what I might suggest is to implement additional features based on the device. The chance is high though, that all Samsung device will behave in the same way.

Comment: Then, we need to fix for the Samsung device accessibility issue to satisfy the WCAG standards or we can exclude Samsung device for Accessibility talkback?

Comment: You can't exclude them, no. There are plenty of blind users using Samsung devices, it's an extremely popular major brand.

Answer (score 0):

Please try checking with other apps as well.
Also, samsung has their own in house screen reader named voice assistant which is being developed exclusively by them. It was based on the source code of talk but now a days Talkback is updated a lot with many fixes and features. So, please try your app with both the screen readers and observe the results. if still both the screen readers don't work properly, then there may be some underlying issue with the UI implementation.